# How to run a process in "Run as administrator" inside a click once application with out asking UAC prompt?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run the secedit.exe in admin mode inside a click once application. Since i am using **click once application** i will not able to make changes in application manifest requestedExecutionLevel. The problem here is it will ask for UAC prompt. Is there any way to run as administrator with out asking UAC in click once application?

Below is the code for run as administrator

```
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\secedit.exe");
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/export /cfg ""{0}"" /quiet", tempFile);
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I found this on the internet.

http://antscode.blogspot.co.at/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html

Comment: @Mathias the problem here is, it will ask for UAC prompt. How to avoid asking UAC prompt